# Met undefined reference when use glib in ubuntu

Tags: glib

I've searched about this a lot. And tried a lot. Just don't know where I go wrong.

Here is my code, it's very simple:

```
#include <glib.h>
int main()
{
    int *ip=g_new(int,1);
    *ip=42;
    return *ip;
}
```

First I try apt-get libglib2.0-dev in my Ubuntu and Mint, when it's done, compile with:

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0` -o main main.c
/tmp/ccYFljQD.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `g_malloc_n'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:3: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

And the output of pkg-config:

```
$ pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0
-I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -lglib-2.0
```

So it's not working, then I try to compile from source and install one by my own.
I've apt-get libffi-dev, autogen and configure, make, make install, that's all okay.

```
$ pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0
-I/home/donpope/software/include/glib-2.0 -I/home/donpope/software/lib/glib-2.0/include -L/home/donpope/software/lib -lglib-2.0
```

Yet compile with the same error:

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0` -o main main.c
/tmp/cctR3iEq.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `g_malloc_n'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:3: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

So I need some help here. Thank you!

Update:
Later I try this in a RedHat with older gcc. And it's just okay.

Comment: Don't use `pkg-config --cflags --libs`: compiler flags and linker flags are positional. Split `--cflags` and `--libs` and get the cflags first and the libs after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this Makefile in my glib sandbox:

```
PKGS=glib-2.0
CFLAGS+=$(shell pkg-config --cflags $(PKGS))
LDFLAGS+=$(shell pkg-config --libs $(PKGS))

%: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@ $(LIBS) $(LDFLAGS)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -c -o $@

%: %.o
    $(CC) $< -o $@ $(LIBS) $(LDFLAGS)
```

Starting from this and tweaking, you should be able to figure out the exact commandline and compile your program.

Also, you should make sure that your PKG_CONFIG_PATH is properly updated to contain the path where you installed glib (typically in PREFIX/lib/pkgconfig).

Comment: It's okay when put -lglib-2.0 at last. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 18.04 here. I had to place all my glib flags at the end of the compile statement, even after the source `.c` file. So this compiles fine:

```
gcc -Wall -o bfs bfs.c `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0` `pkg-config --libs glib-2.0`
```

but this does not :

```
gcc -Wall -o bfs `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0` `pkg-config --libs glib-2.0` bfs.c

    /tmp/ccvWsLk3.o: In function `newGraph':
    bfs.c:(.text+0x58): undefined reference to `g_hash_table_new'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Which drove me nuts for a while as I was taught that it's always good style to place the source file at the end of the compile statement. :p